# ScintillaNet - Working out what line a user clicks on

Tags: mouse, scintilla

I'm using the [ScintillaNet](http://www.codeplex.com/ScintillaNET) text box control to display some search results and I want to be able to detect when the user double clicks / right clicks on a line in the results so that I can work out which hit they are clicking on.

Does anyone have any ideas on the best way of doing this?  I can think of a few ways but they all seem a bit "hacky" to me.

Answer (score 2):

to get the line number from cursor position, you could use something like this

```
scintilla1.Lines.FromPosition(scintilla1.CurrentPos).Number
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new version of [ScintillaNET](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET) you can use a better function to get the current line number:

```
scintilla1.Lines.Current.Number()
```

I was able to attach an event handler to `SelectionChanged` event and then, get the current line number to do what you've asked.